# Fixed-size arrays in a procedure - Pascal Zim

Tags: arrays, pascal, procedure

I have a subject in school named something like "Informatic Aplications" (don't know the right word in english). I have an exercise that I was trying to resolve (studying for the test about procedures and functions). But I don't know how to declare an array in a procedure.

The exercise is the next:

> Write a program in Pascal, which allows you to register distances travelled, in ten days of work. 
>     1) Declare an array of ten elements (one dimension) to register the ditances travelled. 2) Create the procedure InsiraDist, to able the user to type the ten distances to the array.

There are more steps, but if I learn how to open a fixed-size array in a procedure, I can do the rest.

I translated the exercise from portuguese to english, so it may not be the best english you read.

I don't know if it matters, but I've seen some explanations (never to a fixed-size array (we know that the array is going to be something like array [1..10] of real, in this case)) where they open an array in const or type. In classes we always opened an array in var.

Comment: What do you mean with "opening" an array? Do you mean "declaring an array"? And do you know the difference between type, const or var? They are not nearly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I meant "declaring an array". I chose the wrong word when I was translating, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass an array in pascal, declare the type:

```
Type
  TMyDistanceArray = array[1..10] of real;
```

Then just declare the procedure:

```
procedure InsiraDist( var distance : TMyDistanceArray);
begin
  // Edit the contents of distance[1]..distance[10]
end;
```

The `var` declaration before the array parameter, means that the array is passed by reference. Any change of the `distance` parameter will operate directly on the passed array. If the array parameter is prefixed by `const` instead, the compiler would complain if you try to make changes. Without any prefix, all changes would end up inside the procedure only, since a copy of the array would be passed.

```
var
  myArray : TMyDistanceArray; 
begin
  InsiraDist(myArray); // Edit the array
  ...
```

Comment: I guess he should also declare a global variable of that type and pass that to the procedure. He doesn't quite seem to know the difference between const, var and type yet, ISTM.

Comment: Yes, it is true. In classes, my teacher never used Type. I only knew var or const.